# create a scala command line application

Tags: scala, command-line-interface

I was about creating a command line interface for my project that is composed with many applications.

I want to be able to run my applications with something similar to the following :

`launch app --op val ... argument ...`

I used [scopt](https://github.com/scopt/scopt) to write another application `launch` with accepts a command `app` and some options and arguments.

It works as expected as far as I execute the `launch` application using `sbt`, and this is very annoying for me.

My question is : 
Is there any other way to run the application directly from the terminal using something like the one written above.

**Edit 1 :**

I'll be migrating from `sbt` to `gradle`

Comment: sorry, i don't understand the question. scopt don't need sbt for launching apps.

Comment: @volia17 this is my question how to execute the application without sbt

Comment: how will you be running it? `java -jar...`?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [SBT assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin. It automatically creates a JAR file that contains all dependencies. If you define a `mainClass`, then it creates a runnable JAR that can be run with `java -jar <jarfile>`.

If you are on Linux (or possibly MacOS), then you can make it [prepend a shebang](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#prepending-shebang), which makes the resulting JAR file directly executable.

Comment: thank you, I'm preparing to migrate to grade (I've edited my question). Is there any similar way

Comment: Don't change your question. That'll invalidate the answers. Ask a new question.

Comment: this is not a change. this is just an added details